# Можно ли через один профиль публикации опубликовать под разные платформы?

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

В общем, в Visual Studio есть кнопка Publish и там предлагают выбрать платформы и все такое.

Собственно, вопрос в том, а можно ли используя 1 профиль указать несколько Taget Runtime?

Скажем, я хочу получить выхлоп под X86 и X64? В интерфейсе такой возможности нет... Неужели, нужно несколько профилей делать?

Comment: Очень похоже что да, не пробовал еще руками редактировать csproj и publish.profile, может что и получится, но мало вероятно. Но всегда можно вместо кнопки публиковать в студии написать батник с последовательной публикацией нужных профилей.

Comment: @rdorn По идее, в .csprog можно настроить мультитагет платформ, т.е собирать под разные версии фреймворков, но что-то по паблишу подобного не нашел=(

Comment: Перечитал доки по публикации - ничего. xml в профиле поддерживает единственный уровень элементов, так что без вариантов. Под каждую публикацию отдельный профиль. Думаю это связано с поддержкой CI/CD, чтобы можно было настроить автоматическую сборку и публикацию конкретной конфигурации на конкретную платформу и не делать при этом лишних проверок или параметров. Сейчас достаточно в параметрах указать только имя профиля. При мультиконфиге было бы нужно указать еще и вложенный конфиг публикации.